# Rails change input type in a form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form for creating posts in rails. I made the body optional. I use ckeditor for editing the body details, but it takes some time to load and since the body is optional I don't want to always load it.

I use a normal text_area input type and when a user clicks on it I want to replace that text_area with my cjtext_area field.

I am currently trying that with a jQuery function that works if I pass in some text, but not if I pass in my whole textarea.

This is how my dummy text_area looks like:

```
<%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Enter more optional details...", cols: 25, rows: 3, required: true, id: 'textarea', :onclick=>"replaceField(#{f.cktext_area :body});"%>
```

This is my jQuery to change the text_area with a value that is passed into the function:

```
function replaceField(ckeditor)
{
    $("#form_body").replaceWith('<div id="form_body">'+ckeditor+'</div>');
}
```

As I mentioned before, this works if I pass in some text, but not if I pass in the whole `f.cktext_area` field.

Are there any other ways I could achieve this?

Comment: I would probably have the server spit out all the HTML, with a 'hidden' class (or similar) on the ckeditor input (or around it on a div). Then the click handler just needs to do a couple of class toggles. Obviously some CSS would handle the 'hidden' case. This depends on what triggers the loading of the editor. The js handler may need to 'activate' the ckeditor.

Comment: I did exactly that and it worked like a charm!